# Android get number of tries made for unlocking SIM programmatically

Tags: java, android, gsm, telephony

I am unlocking SIM PIN dynamically through my app via these lines

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int state = manager.getSimState();

if(state == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED || state == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED)
{
  try {

   @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
   Class clazz = Class.forName(manager.getClass().getName());

   Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
   m.setAccessible(true);
   ITelephony it = (ITelephony) m.invoke(manager);
   if (it.supplyPin(simPin)) {
       Toast.makeText(context,"SIM UnLocked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   } else {
       Toast.makeText(context,"SIM UNLOCK FAILED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

  } catch (Exception e) {
 // 
     e.printStackTrace();
  }

}else{
  Toast.makeText(context,"SIM is not Locked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

now I want to know how much number of tries already made to unlock the SIM like default SIM PIN/PUK unlocker tells"two attempts left" . let me know if there is any possibility.

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: No direct way, you may put no. of tries count in SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

Just create an `int` that counts from 3 to 0 if sim unlock fails..

> int attempts = 3;
>
> } else {
>
> Toast.makeText(context,"SIM UNLOCK FAILED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>
> attempts --;
>      }

Comment: It would probably be more practical to move the attempts counter somewhere static so that it can be tracked and maintained. Keeping it in what I assume is a method doesn't provide much purpose since it appears to go out of scope as a single-pass method.

Comment: this does not work when the attempts are made through other app.  basically I want to get this value from SIM if there it is present.

Comment: hmm, did some research but i cant find an other option